# How to plot ggplotly and class "c('chorddiag', 'htmlwidget')" plots together

Tags: r, ggplotly, chord-diagram

I am trying to plot the following two graphs chord and plt_interactive

```
library(igraph)
library(tidygraph)
library(chorddiag)
library(ggplot2)
m <- matrix(c(11975,  5871, 8916, 2868,
               1951, 10048, 2060, 6171,
               8010, 16145, 8090, 8045,
               1013,   990,  940, 6907),
               byrow = TRUE,
               nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
groupnames <- c("black", "blonde", "brown", "red")
row.names(m) <- groupnames
colnames(m) <- groupnames

chord= chorddiag(m,type = "bipartite")

plt <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_bar(aes(x= factor(cyl)))+ coord_flip()
plt_interactive <- ggplotly(plt)
```

1. I used to do the following code for two ggplotly graphs:

   `plotly::subplot(f3, f4, nrows=2, heights = c(0.1, 0.9), margin = c(0,0,0.1,0))`

But now I was not sure how to combine those two into subplots as they are different types of graph

2. I also tried the `patchwork` library and do `f3 + f4` but it did now work either
3. I also tried `cowplot` library and do `plot_grid(f3, f4)` with no luck

Any help is very appreciated!
[image]

Comment: What is the output format you are thinking of? To keep them interactive, you could knit a html document, and that would work without issues. Side by side plots work like described in https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/multi-column-layout.html. If you want  to save static images, `rbokeh::widget2png` could help you create a static image from the chord diagram, but that is probably not your goal.

Comment: hi. I updated the question. the issue that I knit to HTML file that dynamically generates tabs. and inside the tab there will be graphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can glue the "plots" together using `htmltools::browsable`. Try this:

```
library(htmltools)
browsable(
  tagList(list(
    tags$div(
      #style = 'width:80%;display:block;float:left;',
      plt_interactive
    ),
    tags$div(
      #style = 'width:20%;display:block;float:left;',
      chord
    )
  ))
)
```

An alternative approach would be to use `crosstalk::bscols(plt_interactive, chord)`.